# How to find dropped data after using Pandas merge in python?

Tags: python, pandas

My Dataframe looks like following.I am using Pandas merge function to merge two dataframes, and I am trying to find row that was dropped. Is there a way in Pandas or python to track this ?

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(({'Name':('A','B','C'),'Age':(34,23,90)}))
df2=pd.DataFrame(({'Name':('A','B','D'),'Add':('rt','ct','pt')}))
pd.merge(df1,df2,on='Name')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with outer join and parameter `indicator=True`:

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='Name', indicator=True, how='outer')
print (df)
  Name   Age  Add      _merge
0    A  34.0   rt        both
1    B  23.0   ct        both
2    C  90.0  NaN   left_only
3    D   NaN   pt  right_only
```

Last filter no both rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df[df['_merge'] != 'both'])
  Name   Age  Add      _merge
2    C  90.0  NaN   left_only
3    D   NaN   pt  right_only
```

Another solution is filtering with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and inverting mask by `~`:

```
print (df1[~df1['Name'].isin(df2['Name'])])
  Name  Age
2    C   90

print (df2[~df2['Name'].isin(df1['Name'])])
  Name Add
2    D  pt
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to create function to display only rows that are not present in Dataframes ?

Comment: @Data_is_Power - What is expected output? `print (df[df['_merge'] != 'both'])` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
merge = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='Name', indicator=True, how='outer')
print (merge)
#drop dataframe
del df1
del df2
```